# how to Convert ByteArray to AudioBuffer and play in Javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, extjs

I want to decode an bytearray to audiobuffer and play my wav file in browser using JS. 
Here the code i am using but while clicking on play button i am getting an exception i.e. "Unable to decode audio Data".

```
{
    if (!window.AudioContext){
        if (!window.webkitAudioContext){
            alert("Your browser does not support any AudioContext and cannot play back this audio.");
            return;
        }
    }

   var context = new AudioContext();
   var arr = me.queueStore.getAt(0).data.ByteAudio;
   var arrayBuffer = new ArrayBuffer(arr.length);
   var bufferView = new Uint8Array(arrayBuffer);
    for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
          bufferView[i] = arr[i];
    }    
    context.decodeAudioData(bufferView, function (buffer) {
    var source = context.createBufferSource(); // creates a sound source
    source.buffer = buffer;                    // tell the source which sound to play
    source.connect(context.destination);                            
    source.start(0);
  });
}
```

Comment: Got the answer , here the solution for this : Use 64bit string to play media files instead converting to audio buffer :  me.fileString = "data:audio/wav;base64," + data.Tone; var audio = new Audio(fileString); audio.play();

Answer (score 0):

Got the answer , here the solution for this : Use 64bit string to play media files instead converting to audio buffer :
`me.fileString = "data:audio/wav;base64," + data.tonebyteArray; 
var audio = new Audio(fileString); 
audio.play();`